# Not working in language on header liferay theme

Tags: themes, liferay

I Add

```
<span id="themeDockLanguagePortlet">$taglibLiferay.language()</span>
```

or

```
$taglibLiferay.language()
```

to header liferay theme, but when click on language , do not see any change in the appearance of the portal.
but copy up code to portlet, i see change with click on language, but this change on language portlet, namely, language do not work on other portlet and only portlett language do work.
help me!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Language switch taglib does not work](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-48238)

This is a known issue and the workaround is to use - $taglibLiferay.language("fm", null, "_82_languageId", 3)